# nginx domain with and without wildcard

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have nginx configuration file which has to server example.com and www.example.com.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;


    auth_basic "example Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    root   /projects/www/example;

    index   index.html;

    location ~* \.(html|js|jpg|png|gif|css|perfumes|imgs|map|fonts|otf)$ {
        index  index.do index.html index.htm;
        access_log off;
    }



    location /.protected {
            access_log off;
            auth_basic off;
    }

    location /health {
        access_log off;
        auth_basic off;
    }

    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
    }

    location /hello {
          proxy_pass              http://localhost:8282;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

I am trying to protect this domain for now, cuz we are preparing the launch. But there is only link which should let the requests pass through without password, if a link has '.protected' in it.

For example,

www.example.com/.protected/file1.txt should be allowed without entering a password.

It is working ok, but the issue is example.com/.protected/file1.txt (without 'www').

If I type only domain name 'example.com' (without 'www'), it automatically redirects to www.example.com as configured, but 'example.com/.protected/file1.txt' doesn't redirect to 'www.example.com/.protected/file1.txt'.   It seems if the domain name has some paths, the domain name (without 'www') doesn't redirect to 'www.example.com'

I am getting 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host:'

Is there anything wrong with my configuration file?

Comment: Which host is not resolved by curl, can you please put curl verbose log.

It seems to me that your nginx config is okay, may be you dont have host entry for www.example.com from where you are running the curl command.

Comment: This is all I get.  * Could not resolve host: example.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com.    i added 'www.example.com' on DNS record type 'A'.

Comment: Can you ping example.com and www.example.com?

Comment: i can ping www.example.com, but i can't ping example.com. I have two webservers and one load balancer. The load balancer sends a request to these two web servers. The web servers are up and running.

Comment: so you cant reach to example.com thats the actual issue, I think you have issue with DNS entry. Just put hosts entry for example.com and check it out.

I think things will work like charm!

Comment: @user826323 can you do a DNS lookup for 'example.com'. I think you have not pointed 'example.com' to your server's IP.

Comment: it's resolved. i had to create example.com in the A record.